# Android online preferences

Tags: android

I remember reading about a type of setting that can now be used with Android, where you change a value online and all of your apps can get the setting. Like an online global variable.

Can anyone please tell me how this API is called?

Answer (score 0):

you can you XML or JSON parsing.you can follow this site:

```
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but what I was looking for is a class that does this. I read about it before but cannot remember the name of it. It was specifically for allowing you to store app settings on like, the app would retrieve the setting. It didn't require any HTTP type programming, it is more simple I think.

Comment: To clarify my question..

There is a way that you can get each android app to load settings (like default user preferences etc) from an online location.

I think I saw a mention of it on the Google I/O 2013.

It meant that instead of changing a constant value in your app and redeploying it to the Google Play store, you could just change the value online and ALL apps would then get the changed setting value.

It didn't require having to write code to do this.